# JS variables definition inside curly braces

Tags: javascript

I was taking a look to an old javascript file and I noticed a function like this:

```
function mainFunction() {

  var foo = new objFoo();

  foo.name = "fooname";
  foo.desc = "foodesc";

  // some instructions here

  {

    var bar = new objBar();

    bar.name = foo.name;
    bar.desc = foo.desc;

    // some other instructions here

  }

  return(foo);

}
```

My question is: what is the purpose (if there is one) of those curly braces surrounding the `bar` object definition?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Curly braces like that in JavaScript define a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block). They *can* be used to contain scope if a variable is initialised using either `let` or `const`, but since the variable in your example is initialised using `var`, they don't actually do anything (unless there's a statement in the preceding line like an `if` or `while` etc.).

Just going by the code you've given us, I think it's a mis-interpretation of code or a mis-understanding of JavaScript by the developer. To contain scope in JavaScript using `var` variables, you'll need to write closure like this:

```
function mainFunction() {

  var foo = new objFoo();

  foo.name = "fooname";
  foo.desc = "foodesc";

  // some instructions here

  (function () {

    var bar = new objBar();

    bar.name = foo.name;
    bar.desc = foo.desc;

    // some other instructions here

  }());

  return(foo);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The curly braces define a block with a local scope. You may define variables using `const` or `let` in the block the scopes of which are limited to the block.

For example:

```js
const a = "world"
{
  const a = "hello"
  console.log(a)
}
console.log(a)
```

Using `var` inside the block of curly braces is dangerous since it overwrites variables with the same name that are defined outside the block. If you use `var` declarations instead of `const`/`let`, the only advantage of a block can be a better legibility.

```js
var a = "world"
{
  var a = "hello"
  console.log(a)
}
console.log(a)
```